# Defining principal ideals in commutative rings without identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm just learning basic ring theory and had a question about the definition of a principal ideal. For a commutative ring $R$ *with unity*, Fraleigh defines the principal ideal generated by $a\in R$ as $\langle a\rangle = \{ra:r\in R\}$. My question is, why do we need to assume that $R$ has a unity? It seems like $\langle a\rangle$ fits the criterion for an ideal without it. Is this the standard definition? If so, do we include the unity condition so that we can say that $a\in \langle a\rangle$? Also, if we require that every ring have a unity, wouldn't we have that the entire ring is a principal ideal of itself, since $R=\langle1\rangle$?

Comment: You can also talk about principal ideals in rings without unit. Nothing prevents you from doing that.

Comment: If you like to write ideals with angly-brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`, so that you get $\langle a\rangle$ instead of the immensly uglier $<a>$ :-)

Comment: I am not familiar with non-unital ring theory, but the fact that $a\in Ra$ requires $1\in R$ seems relevant. There is another definition of principal ideal as that generated by a single element, where we define the ideal generated by a set to be the smallest ideal containing the set (so it is the intersection of all such). On *this* definition, $Ra$ would be different from $\langle a\rangle$ (the smallest ideal containing $a$) if $R$ doesn't have a $1$. In $R=2\Bbb Z$ for instance, $2R=4\Bbb Z$ but $\langle2\rangle=2\Bbb Z$. Also yes, $R=\langle1\rangle$ in any unital ring (why do you ask?).

Comment: That $a\in Ra$ does not *require* that $R$ have a unit: for example, $a$ may be idempotent or the ring may have local units.

Comment: @anon it was pretty much for the reason you mentioned (the ideal generated by $a$ wouldn't necessarily be the same as the smallest ideal containing $a$). I was just looking for the most general definition for this term, and was just curious as to why the book made this requirement.

Comment: @anon it's one of the things I don't particularly like about Fraleigh's book. He doesn't define things in the most general way, and then restrict his focus to whatever he wants to talk about. Instead, he makes stronger requirements for many of his definitions than necessary.

Comment: «Defining things in the most general way» is a terribly bad way to write a textbook on basic ring theory (or basic anything, really)! And why would an author write a book and *not* restrict focus to whatevery it is *he* wants to talk about? It is *his* book! Your complaints about the book are quite strange! :-)

Comment: Well, a narrowed focus could be a cocktail of familiarity, interest, convenience, scope, caution, foresight, pedagogy, etc. It'd probably be difficult to tease out the exact mixture of these variables in any author's decision-making process. Or an author even could have just ended up with a suboptimal exposition because nobody's perfect. At any rate, going beyond a textbook by experimentally tweaking the parameters in definitions and observing the consequences is good exercise.

Comment: @mariano Yes, that is a good point. Didn't mean to put down Fraleigh... I think it is a very good book. It just seems like it would save someone the effort of having to re-verify that many of the results are true in more general cases

Comment: The purpose of a textbook on basic algebra is not to do everything, but to introduce the reader to, well, basic algebra. There are other books with other purposes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I've been told that one should see where every assumption in a definition or statement is made when reading a proof, and to see why it is necessary.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez But yes, I see your point. You can only do so much. Especially with an introduction to the subject

Comment: Well, why does one restrict rings to have two operations? There is no obstacle in considering sets with an arbitrary number (even infinite) of operations, not all of them binary but with arbitrary arities, satisfying arbitrary conditions; there is a whole subject, called universal algebra, devoted to the study of these things. Rings are just a super-ultra-special case of this. Would you rather read a book that starts with that? Have you tried to seee why he just considers rings? :-)

Comment: It is also not that «one can do so much»: one does not *want* to do more!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I wouldn't want to start off that way, so I see what you mean. I have a lot to learn about the way textbooks are written and about mathematics in general. I'm still very novice, but just trying to understand a little more.

Comment: I think the smallest ideal containing $a$ could be written as $\{ na + ra \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}, r \in R \}$.  (Which happens to look related to the standard extension of a non-unital ring to a unital ring.)

Answer (score 2):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

> why do we need to assume that R has a unity? It seems like ⟨⟩ fits the criterion for an ideal without it.

If $R$ does not have identity, then you're correct: $\{aR\mid r\in R\}$ *is* an ideal.  However, one doesn't know whether or not $a\in aR$ when there's no identity in $R$. That's something we would really like $\langle a\rangle$ to satisfy.

Comment: Just saying that I like that you work on these. Ok in most cases the OP won't read the answer BUT since the questions will pop up in search results it is definitely worth it.